# What late game armor builds work for longswords?

Tags: monster-hunter-now

My favorite weapon type is the Longsword so I'm trying to plan ahead on what armor parts to focus my resources on.  Which armor parts should I be upgrading with my resources, and what skills should I be prioritizing?